# Iterate through Collection<List<Integer>>

Tags: java, collections, guava

I use Guava library to generate permutations of integers `1`, `2` and `3`.

```
Collection<List<Integer>> vehCombinations = Collections2.orderedPermutations(vehicles);
```

Next I need to iterate through `vehCombinations` and check each permutation with respect to some constraint:

```
for (int j=0; j<vehCombinations.size(); j++)
{
  List<Integer> veh = vehCombinations.get(i);
}
```

`vehCombinations.get(i)` is not allowed.

So, how do I extract permutations from `vehCombinations`?

Comment: "**Perturbation**: 1) anxiety; mental uneasiness. 2) A deviation of a system, moving object, or process from its regular or normal state of path, caused by an outside influence.". "**Permutation**: a way, esp. one of several possible variations, in which a set or number of things can be ordered or arranged.". You probably meant the second one :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a foreach, like this:

```
for(List<Integer> veh : vehCombinations){
    veh.doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may use the for each syntax:

```
for(List<Integer> veh : vehCombinations) {
  // Do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
for(List<Integer> veh : vehCombinations){
   // write your logic
}
```

> Sometimes if you need to write your own collection extensions. Perhaps
>   if you want to add special behavior when elements are added to a list,
>   or you want to write an Iterable that's actually backed by a database
>   query. Guava provides a number of utilities to make these tasks easier
>   for you, and for us.

Take a look at this stuffs

**[Forwarding Decorators](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionHelpersExplained)**

In that take a look at

1.**PeekingIterator**

```
List<E> result = Lists.newArrayList();
PeekingIterator<E> iter = Iterators.peekingIterator(source.iterator());
while (iter.hasNext()) {
  E current = iter.next();
  while (iter.hasNext() && iter.peek().equals(current)) {
    // skip this duplicate element
    iter.next();
  }
  result.add(current);
}
```

2.**AbstractIterator**

```
public static Iterator<String> skipNulls(final Iterator<String> in) {
  return new AbstractIterator<String>() {
    protected String computeNext() {
      while (in.hasNext()) {
        String s = in.next();
        if (s != null) {
          return s;
        }
      }
      return endOfData();
    }
  };
}
```

3.**AbstractSequentialIterator**

```
 Iterator<Integer> powersOfTwo = new AbstractSequentialIterator<Integer>(1) { // note the initial value!
     protected Integer computeNext(Integer previous) {
       return (previous == 1 << 30) ? null : previous * 2;
     }
   };
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use iterator:

```
Iterator<List<Integer>> pageIterator = vehCombinations.iterator();
    while (pageIterator.hasNext()) {
        List<Integer> list = (List<Integer>) pageIterator.next();
    }
```